# Crashing on sqlite3_step line?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, crash, exc-bad-access

Crashing on sqlite3_step line?

I am just deleting the row from the database. It throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS sometimes not always.

Below is the screenshot of code.

Any suggestions guys.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide stack traces?

Comment: `EXE_BAD_ACCESS` occurs when u r trying to use released objects, enable zombie and check where the actual issue is.

Comment: @vishy, there is only 1 variable called "sqlite3_stmt *stmt2" in which it is causing Exc_Bad_Access. Any other reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The above problem is due to multiple write process to the DB. I synchronized the DB operations. Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: @dillip.ajm I facing the exact same problem, I know this thread is very old but could you provide how you solve this problem?

Comment: @majorl3oat this problem was due to multiple write operations on db at the same time. I was downloading the data from multiple urls asyncronously and writing on db. Just syncronize your db writing operations i.e write on db once at a time, dont use multiple threads to write data on db. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You have not opened the database using

```
if(sqlite3_open([databaseName UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
      // perform your operations here e.g. delete, insert, update
}
else
{
      NSString *databaseName = [self.GetDocumentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"yourDatabaseName.sqlite"];
      sqlite3_open([databaseName UTF8String], &db);

      // perform your operations here e.g. delete, insert, update
}
```

Refer Deleting Records in [this](http://klanguedoc.hubpages.com/hub/IOS-5-SDK-Database-Insert-Update-Delete-with-SQLite-and-Objective-C-C-How-To)

Comment: I am opening the DB on app launch and after this method is called. Any method to check whether DB is open?